# Are there negative modifiers for moving and making a range attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, ranged-attack

If you take your move action before you use your standard action to fire a ranged weapon, do you suffer from some kind of penalty? And what if you do this via the Shot on the Run feat?

Comment: Related: [In 3.5 does movement speed add damage or attack power to weapons?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28154/4563)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, there are no penalties.  There's no place in the rules I can really quote here, because it simply isn't considered.  The assumption is that if you both move and attack, your movement does not interfere with the attack.  There are no [combat modifiers](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/combatModifiers.html) related to movement, and it isn't mentioned under either the [movement rules](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/movement.html) or the [general combat rules](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/actionsInCombat.html)

The same goes for Shot on the Run.  (The feat represents the special training your character has to accomplish the maneuver, after all!)

There *are* explicit penalties when shooting [from horseback](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#mounted-combat):

> You can use ranged weapons while your mount is taking a double move, but at a –4 penalty on the attack roll. You can use ranged weapons while your mount is running (quadruple speed), at a –8 penalty.

Keep in mind that, generally, if you take a ranged attack and a move, you've spent roughly 3 seconds aiming.  That seems like plenty of time for a trained adventurer!

Comment: Not being able to full-attack is a **huge** downside, though it's not an explicit penalty; worth mentioning. Also your statement that there are no combat modifiers related to movement is inaccurate; the Charge maneuver gives you combat modifiers directly related to moving a certain way.