# Is the effect of how speed affects damage addressed in the rules anywhere?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures, d20-modern

Increases in weight affect damage, as per the improvised weapon rules on heavy items.

Is the effect of how speed affects damage addressed in the rules anywhere?

Any official sources from the listed tags are usable for answers.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Does movement speed add damage or attack power to weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28154/8610)

Answer (score 2):

The closest would be rules on [falling objects](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#fallingObjects) which has a chart for objects doing damage based on how far they fall before they hit a creature, i.e. how fast they are going at the time of impact.

> Just as characters take damage when they fall more than 10 feet, so too do they take damage when they are hit by falling objects.
>
> Objects that fall upon characters deal damage based on their weight and the distance they have fallen.
>
> For each 200 pounds of an object’s weight, the object deals 1d6 points of damage, provided it falls at least 10 feet. Distance also comes into play, adding an additional 1d6 points of damage for every 10-foot increment it falls beyond the first (to a maximum of 20d6 points of damage).
>
> Objects smaller than 200 pounds also deal damage when dropped, but they must fall farther to deal the same damage. Use Table: Damage from Falling Objects to see how far an object of a given weight must drop to deal 1d6 points of damage.
>
> For each additional increment an object falls, it deals an additional 1d6 points of damage.
>
> Objects weighing less than 1 pound do not deal damage to those they land upon, no matter how far they have fallen.